# Get Top 10 Value by Group

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
ID    |State|# of Orders
-----------------------------
1001  | CA  |   39
1002  | CA  |   100
1003  | CA  |   32
1004  | CA  |   9
1005  | IL  |   60
1006  | IL  |   67
1007  | IL  |   47
1008  | IL  |   35
1009  | MA  |   67
1010  | MA  |   23
1011  | MA  |   3
1012  | MA  |   38
1013  | MO  |   9 
1014  | MO  |   45
1015  | MO  |   75
1016  | MO  |   8
1017  | AZ  |   48
1018  | AZ  |   100
1019  | AZ  |   75
1020  | AZ  |   72
```

How can I get a result that returns top 5 ID per each State that has the highest # of order?

```
select ID, State, # of Orders
from table
???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it all on one line per state, you can do:

```
select state, substring_index(group_concat(id order by NumOrders desc), ',', 5) as top5
from table t
group by state;
```

You can also do it with one line per state, assuming no duplicates:

```
select id, state, numorders
from table t
where (select count(*)
       from table t2
       where t2.state = t.state and
             (t2.numorders > numorders or
              t2.numorders = t.numorders and t2.id <= t.id
             )
      ) <= 5;
```

Comment: actually when i change `<=5` to `<=3`, it still returns all the data as if I did `select * from table`.